# is ok to use the same variable in two hierarchies?

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I have a dataset with two levels: the city level and person level, at the city level i have the categorical variable "poverty level", in my research estimating the effect of the  "poverty level" is of paramount importance.

I am not sure how to include the poverty level in my model.

Here is mini example of my data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

# dataset with the information of the cities
city_df <- data.frame(
  city = LETTERS[1:15],
  poverty_level = rep(c("C1", "C2", "C3"), 5) 
)

set.seed(123)
# dataset with the information of the persons
persons_df <- data.frame(
  age = rpois(100, 20),
  earnings = rnorm(100, 100, 10) |> abs(),
  city = sample(LETTERS[1:15], 100, replace = T)
)

full_df = persons_df |> 
          left_join(city_df)
```

The data looks like this:

```
    age  earnings city poverty_level
1    17 113.76610    A            C1
2    23  97.58023    A            C1
3    19  87.22549    A            C1
4    18  76.00802    A            C1
5    14 103.62370    A            C1
6    22  88.22033    A            C1
7    21 117.97140    A            C1
8    21 119.00900    A            C1
9    27 101.92442    A            C1
10   12 103.39957    B            C2
11   25 107.90190    B            C2
12   18 109.02506    B            C2
13   14  99.11315    B            C2
14   29  99.81366    B            C2
15   17 103.14153    B            C2
```

Including poverty_level as a random and fixed effect:

```
model_1 <- lmer(earnings ~ age + poverty_level + (1 + poverty_level|city), data=full_df)
summary(model_1)


Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: earnings ~ age + poverty_level + (1 + poverty_level | city)
   Data: full_df

REML criterion at convergence: 747.4

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.38084 -0.59015 -0.02984  0.64791  2.18420 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name            Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr       
 city     (Intercept)     0.000e+00 0.000e+00            
          poverty_levelC2 4.633e-11 6.806e-06   NaN      
          poverty_levelC3 1.246e+01 3.530e+00   NaN -0.92
 Residual                 1.143e+02 1.069e+01            
Number of obs: 100, groups:  city, 15

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)      98.4492     5.7722  17.056
age               0.1084     0.2800   0.387
poverty_levelC2  -0.9915     2.6323  -0.377
poverty_levelC3  -1.0670     3.0834  -0.346

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) age    pvr_C2
age         -0.947              
pvrty_lvlC2 -0.231  0.003       
pvrty_lvlC3 -0.116 -0.083  0.427
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

Including poverty_level only as a fixed effect:

```
model_2 <- lmer(earnings ~ age + poverty_level + (1|city), data=full_df)
summary(model_2)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: earnings ~ age + poverty_level + (1 | city)
   Data: full_df

REML criterion at convergence: 748

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.34529 -0.64463 -0.03629  0.70258  2.15640 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 city     (Intercept)   0.0     0.00   
 Residual             117.7    10.85   
Number of obs: 100, groups:  city, 15

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)      97.9364     5.7683  16.978
age               0.1347     0.2793   0.482
poverty_levelC2  -0.9907     2.6708  -0.371
poverty_levelC3  -1.3722     2.6670  -0.515

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) age    pvr_C2
age         -0.945              
pvrty_lvlC2 -0.234  0.003       
pvrty_lvlC3 -0.129 -0.109  0.500
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

I can not include the "poverty level" only as a random effect because i need the estimate of its effect.

I am including the "poverty level" correctly in the model_1 or in the model_2?, if not is there a correct way the include the "poverty level" as fixed effect?